# While finding out the most probable location from wavefunction, why don't we set the derivative of probability to zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

I was told that in order to find the most probable location of a particle we have to differentiate the probability density of a wavefunction. I don't quite get it. If we want to find out the $x$ value for which $f(x)$ is maximum we solve $f'(x)=0$.

By similar reasoning, since the probability is given by:

$$P=\int{|\psi|^2dx}$$ $x$ value for maximum probability must be given by:

$$\frac{dP}{dx}= |\psi|^2=0$$

not: $$\frac{d|\psi|^2}{dx}=0$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your second equation has no $x$ dependence after integration.  There's no variable with which to take the derivative. That is, $P$ is not a function of $x$.

Comment: Simply your definition of probability needs a domain of integration, if you integrate a probability density in the whole domain you will always get 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability density function is what you need to differentiate, not the integral.
$$P = \int_D |\psi|^2 dx = 1$$ for any normalized state for $D$ the domain of the problem.
So you have to look at the probability **density**, $f(x) = |\psi(x)|^2$, and find its maximum. More formally, the probability of finding the particle described by $\psi(x)$ within the infinitesimal interval $(x, x+dx)$ is given by
$$\int_x^{x+dx} f(x)dx = |\psi(x)|^2 dx $$

Finding the most probable location, amounts to finding the maximum of $f(x)$ for which you can take derivative and equate it to zero, then solve for $x$. Notice that you technically require a non-zero volume (could be small, but not zero) to actually obtain a non-zero probability. Units make sense therefore, in one dimension
$$\text{probability} = \frac{\text{probability}}{\text{lenth}}\cdot \text{length} = |\psi(x)|^2 \Delta x$$

P.D. Don't confuse with the expected value of the position or, the average of the position.
$$\langle \psi | \hat{x} | \psi \rangle = \int x|\psi(x)|^2dx$$.

Comment: I was told the same thing. I don't understand why. To me it feels like differentiating density to optimise mass.

Comment: What do you mean by optimize mass?

Comment: from the relation: mass=density*volume, if we wanted to optimise mass, we won't differentiate density right?

Comment: Here, the density is NOT the mass density $\rho = \frac{m}{V}$, but the probability density.

Comment: You need to understand better what the integral stands for. It's a DEFINITE integral BTW.

Comment: @Gert So $P$ gives total probability over a range, where as $|\psi|^2$ gives probability at the neighbourhood of $x$ right? But the units of it ($1/m^3$) doesn't seem correct. If it gives probability, shouldn't be dimensionless?

Comment: $f(x) = |\psi(x)|^2$ is the probability **DENSITY** at $x$, hence the units. It is NOT a probability. BTW, the probability of find the particle at $x$ is actually $0$ ($\text{zero}$).

Comment: *gives total probability over a range,* is correct but a little clunky. The definite integral over $x$ to $x+\Delta x$ gives the actual probability of finding the particle in that spatial interval.

Comment: After some digging on probability densities, I finally understand it. Thankyou